# angular onclick select multiple fields get value and change background color

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a calendar when I  select a field I change  his background color and store this field data  in array but when I unselect a field I reset background to normal and empty his value from the array .
in this code I  created the calendar and I can only select one value and  get his value .

Can someone update my code to change background of multiple fields select and store value in an array ?

https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-ives-kly4z

Comment: Can you be more specific? @Latome. I didnt get what you are trying to solve

Comment: I want something like this  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-32fsyf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-overview-example.ts

Comment: I have changed your code in code sandbox. Please check and let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving the selected date in the variable and overriding on click. You need to store in an array or object to keep a track of. I have changed the code in the sandbox and saved. Let me know if this is what you wanted. Link [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-pare-mnbc1?file=/src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Yes that's what I need but I want the format of the date  as ' yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: That is just to store a data. You can create a one more key and store its format in that key from the data model itself

Comment: new Date(your date goes here).toISOString().slice(0,10);

Comment: I can't acces to your code why ? and I have an error Property 'color' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.